# Flutter does not find android sdk - vdcode Ubuntu

Tags: android, flutter, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to setup vscode for flutter development in Ubuntu, but I'm having an issue locating android SDK and accepting the licenses. I installed android studio and ticked everything in SDK manager, then changed flutter config to the android SDK path , but still same error.

```
--> flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS 5.13.0-25-generic,
    locale en_US.UTF-8)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 27.0.1)
    ✗ Flutter requires Android SDK 29 and the Android BuildTools 28.0.3
      To update the Android SDK visit
      https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for
      detailed instructions.
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for
      more details.
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.63.2)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
```

when trying to accept license , I get this

```
--> flutter doctor --android-licenses
Android sdkmanager not found. Update to the latest Android SDK and ensure that
the cmdline-tools are installed to resolve this.
```

Comment: Flutter provides a command to update the Android SDK path:

flutter config --android-studio-dir="/snap/android-studio/current/android-studio"

Comment: try this command may help : sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-29"

Comment: @AbhishekChhabra , not working

Comment: @HardikMehta it says sdkmanager: command not found

Comment: @koko99 if it ain't working then... start from the beginning... come on anydesk if you want. I'll help you to install it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to restart my laptop, then ran again this command inside vscode terminal flutter config --android-sdk "PATH TO ANDROID SDK" , now it works!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that u have Android SDK version 27 but Flutter requires 29.

So u should instal required sdk or higher version.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution by Abo_nosa didn't work but I was able to solve the issue by installing the sdkmanager, following [these steps](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager)